# Is there a simple way to open a readable stream from Mongo in Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream

Using MySQL it is **very easy** to open a readable stream from the database. All we need to do is:

```
function getTableStream() {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE field = value').stream();
}
```

After that we can do things like:

```
getTableStream.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And this is blazing fast. In fact I tried this with something like 85 thousands of rows and it was able to list all the data on the console in less than one minute.

I'm wondering: is it possible to do the same thing with MongoDB? Can we open a readable stream from mongo and get the data from there via streaming?

If it is possible, how is it done with Mongo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`.stream()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#stream) on a native driver cursor to get a readable stream:

```
var stream = collection.find().stream();
stream.on('data', function(doc) {
    console.log(doc);
});
stream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
stream.on('end', function() {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```

Comment: That's quite nice, I didn't now it was that simple. Thanks for the answer! By the way, do you know if there's some way to get the readable stream using Monk?

Comment: @user1620696 Glad it helped. Sorry, I don't use Monk so I can't help you there.